# How to change actionbar title and subtitle font size in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

This is what I try but nothing happen

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.Freshchat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Style1</item>
</style>

<style name="Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

For more context, I am using Freshchat chat widget and want to change the Title and Subtitle font size. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try this your can you `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleTheme"
  app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarSubtitleTheme">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

than create  Style in Style.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarTitleTheme" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <<item name="android:textColor">#FFAA12</item>
    <!-- include other attributes you want to change: textColor, textStyle, etc -->
</style>

<style name="ToolbarSubtitleTheme" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFAA12</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

1>Create an XML file with name `titleview.xml`

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2>In OnCreate method:

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

//if you need to customize anything else about the text, do it here.
//I'm using a custom TextView with a custom font in my layout xml so all I need to do is set title
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(this.getTitle());
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextSize(20);


//assign the view to the actionbar
            this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
        }
```

3>In Manifest file to your Activity Add this line

```
android:label="@string/room_title"
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way will be to create a **custom_action_bar.xml** layout for your action bar as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You title"
        android:textColor="#ff0"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your subtitle"
        android:textColor="#ff0"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you have to set the layout of you custom action bar as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
}
```

Using this method you will be able to easily customize your action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableString` as follows:

```
 SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.manage_prescription));
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(YourActivity.this, Constants.TOOLBAR_TITLE_FONT), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

And user this SpannableString object to set the title to your action bar.